Angular material themes with css variables
I have in my project css variables like below:
:root {
  --color-primary: #65A518;
  --color-primary-hover: #558817;
  --color-primary-dark: #006729;
  --color-white: #FFFFFF;
}

but now I have to add angular material and custom themes.
I read that I need create my custom palette like below:
$custom-brand-primary: (
  50: '#edf3e7',
  100: '#d2e2c3',
  200: '#b4cf9c',
  300: '#95bc74',
  400: '#7fad56',
  500: $custom-primary,
  600: '#609732',
  700: '#558d2b',
  800: '#4b8324',
  900: '#3a7217',
  contrast: (
    50: $black,
    100: $black,
    200: $black,
    300: $black,
    400: $white,
    500: $white,
    600: $white,
    700: $white,
    800: $white,
    900: $white
  )
);

etc
and then in theme.css create custom palette.
So how to mix this approaches? and use css variables in angular material themes?
Is it good practise to mix it?

you are on the right track.
I believe the next step would be to do the following:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$app_theme: mat.define-light-theme(
    (
        color: (
            primary: $custom-brand-primary
         )
    )
);
@include mat.all-component-themes($app_theme);


But it's not my question. I know how to build theme using scss, but I'am asking about using css variables with angular material.
